# Monitoring processes with while(true) loop

Tags: c#, console-application

Is it possible to optimise my console application? It uses up to 60% of CPU because of while(true) loop. 
The idea is to kill Microsoft managment console (services) process every time it starts up. And to start/stop services - use pswrd and console.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        Thread consoleInput = new Thread(_consoleInput);
        consoleInput.Start();
        killProcess();
    }
```

---

```
    static void _consoleInput(){
        getPassword();
        sendServiceCommands();
    }
    static void killProcess(){
        while(true){
            try{
                System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("mmc");
                myProcs[0].Kill();
                }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }           
     }
```

---

Comment: The more % the more optimized it is, usually. A program that iterates 100k objects at 50% usage is likely to be slower than the program that iterates them at 100% usage. If you want to use less CPU per time then you can add a sleep, `while (true) { doStuff(); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); }` to sleep 100ms between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You need System.Threading.Timer. Something like this:

```
public class Killer
{
    protected const int timerInterval = 1000; // define here interval between ticks

    protected Timer timer = new Timer(timerInterval); // creating timer

    public Killer()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;     
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {  
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("mmc");
            myProcs[0].Kill();
        }
        catch {}
    }
}

...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    Killer killer = new Killer();
    Thread consoleInput = new Thread(_consoleInput);
    _consoleInput.Start();
    killer.Start();

    ...

    // whenever you want you may stop your killer
    killer.Stop();
}
```